# Repository Error - FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject. in Atomikos distributed transaction

Tags: spring, jpa, atomikos

I am currently following tutorial of atomikos for distributed transaction using xml configuration. I get error in repository level with message factory bean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject. I think there is no any circular dependency in beans and database connection is also fine. When I removed repository from service implementation then there is no error.

**Error i get in console**

Error creating bean with name 'auctionServiceRequired_TX' defined in class path resource [spring-sender-mysql.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'auctionTarget' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auctionTarget': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'quoteRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quoteRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject

**spring-sender-mysql.xml**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/springa-jpa.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd ">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>application.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="datasourceAtomikos-01"
        class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="uniqueResourceName"><value>JDBC-1</value></property>
        <property name="xaDataSource"><ref bean="xaDataSourceMySQL-01"  /></property>
        <property name="xaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="maxPoolSize">4</prop>
                <prop key="uniqueResourceName">xads1</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="poolSize"><value>4</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="xaDataSourceMySQL-01" class="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource">
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection"><value>true</value></property>
        <property name="user"><value>${jdbc.username}</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value>${jdbc.password}</value></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="forceShutdown"><value>true</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
        <property name="transactionTimeout"><value>300</value></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">

        <property name="transactionManager"><ref bean="atomikosTransactionManager"  /></property>
        <property name="userTransaction"><ref bean="atomikosUserTransaction"  /></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="springJtaPlatformAdapter" class="io.trustaml.AtomikosJtaPlatform">
        <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <bean id="quoteEntityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasourceAtomikos-01"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">io.trustaml.AtomikosJtaPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.transactionType">JTA</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="io.trustaml.model"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="quotePersistenceUnit" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="io.trustaml.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="quoteEntityManager"/>

    <!-- Error in creating this bean -->
    <bean id="auctionTarget" class= "io.trustaml.service.AuctionServiceImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="auctionServiceRequired_TX" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager"><ref bean="transactionManager" /></property>
        <property name="target"><ref bean="auctionTarget"  /></property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="confirm*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, -QuotesConfirmRollbackException, +QuotesNoRollbackException</prop>
                <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS, readOnly</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="auctionServiceRequiresNew_TX" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager"><ref bean="transactionManager" /></property>
        <property name="target"><ref bean="auctionTarget"  /></property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="confirm*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW, -QuotesConfirmRollbackException, +QuotesNoRollbackException</prop>
                <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS, readOnly</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

**Repository**

```
public interface QuoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Quote, Long> {
    List<Quote> findByStatus(String status);
}
```

**Service Implementing repository**

```
@Service
public class AuctionServiceImpl implements AuctionService{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuctionServiceImpl.class);
    private static volatile boolean flipFlop = false;

    @Autowired
    private QuoteRepository quoteRepository;
     
    // other business logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Annotate your QuoteRepository with @Repository.

Comment: adding @repository does not work

Comment: also try to add all your classes/interfaces (if possible) in the same package. Else make sure you use @ComponentScan appropriately to include all your services/components/repositories/configurations.

Comment: @component scan is use if i am using annotation for (service,repository and component) but all bean are configure in xml file so i think that is not required

Comment: Try the "if possible" condition else <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourpackage.name" />

Comment: still facing same problem. I think there is something missing regarding repository once i removed it then every thing work.